# How to replace values of a specified column in a CSV using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, matlab, csv

I have a CSV where the first column gives the weekday. But the problem is that I need to use the CSV in MATLAB, which does not allow string values. So, I want to convert the Sunday to 7, ..., Monday to 1 in the CSV.

But I can't seem to find a way to do that in Ruby. And I can't open the excel manually to do it either because the file size is huge. Specifically, I'm having problem in figuring out the syntax of how to access and point to the specific column I want in Ruby. For example, if the file would have loaded in MATLAB, and if I was still required to convert the weekdays into numbers for some reason, I would have written a simple code like this:

```
for i=1:length(Columns(:,1))
    if Columns(i,1)=='sunday'
        Columns(i,1)=7
    elseif Columns(i,1)=='saturday'
        Columns(i,1)=6
    elseif Columns(i,1)=='friday'
        Columns(i,1)=5
    elseif Columns(i,1)=='thursday'
        Columns(i,1)=4
    elseif Columns(i,1)=='wednesday'
        Columns(i,1)=3
    elseif Columns(i,1)=='tuesday'
        Columns(i,1)=2
    elseif Columns(i,1)=='monday'
        Columns(i,1)=1
    end
end
```

So, I am having problem in figuring out the Ruby equivalent of this statement:

```
for i=1:length(Columns(:,1))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two good CSV libraries in Ruby, I'm assuming based on what you said that the CSV file has no header (if it did, `SmarterCSV` makes things a bit easier).

That said, you wanted to get the first column:

```
require 'csv'

your_csv = CSV.open("your_csv.csv")
# This is the line you wanted:
first_column = your_csv.map(&:first)

# Then to do the weekday conversion (with a Hash):
convert_weekdays = { "sunday" => 1, "monday" => 2, "tuesday" => 3, "wednesday" => 4, "thursday" => 5, "friday" => 6, "saturday" => 7 }

converted = first_column.map { |row| convert_weekdays[row] }
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you wanted, there are a lot of ways to work with CSV files in Ruby.

To save the CSV, you'll want to open a new (or the same) CSV file using CSV.open:

```
your_csv = CSV.open("your_csv.csv")
CSV.open("saved_csv.csv", "w") do |csv|
  your_csv.each { |row| csv << [convert_weekdays[row.first], *row[1...row.size]] }
end
```

Sorry it's a bit inelegant, writing CSV in Ruby is not always the easiest thing! Note the curly braces `{}` are the same as `do end`, but are conventionally used when the inner block is only one line.

**Edit:** this method is perhaps a bit faster with large files:

```
your_csv = CSV.parse("your_csv.csv")
convert_weekdays = { "sunday" => 1, "monday" => 2, "tuesday" => 3, "wednesday" => 4, "thursday" => 5, "friday" => 6, "saturday" => 7 }
by_columns = your_csv.transpose
by_columns.first.map! { |row| convert_weekdays[row] }
CSV.open("saved_csv.csv", "w") do |csv|
  by_columns.transpose.each { |row| csv << row }
end
```

This way, you load the CSV as a two dimensional array, transpose it, and only operate on the first column.

Comment: Hello. Many thanks for that, I am running the code, let's see if it works.

What is `&:` though, and how does it work?

And is it going to edit in the same csv, or create a new csv with some default name? I ask because as of now, when the code is running, I don't see any change in the "date modified" section for the file when I refresh the folder.

Comment: Nope, this is just going to create a local object. You have to resave the CSV on your own. Try using `CSV.open`. This comment thing doesn't really let me elaborate, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: As for `&`, this stands for symbol to proc. You can pass this as a block in ruby, similar to saying `your_csv.map { |row| row.first }`, the `&:` is a handy shortcut when you are calling a single method on each object. The `:first` is a symbol that represents the `first` method, and `&` makes `map` interpret this as a block.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. It works.  I'll need some time to understand it. But if I understand correctly, there's no way to index arrays in Ruby, right? I mean, one can do it in the way you mentioned above, but no `Array(i,j)` operation is possible here, right? In other words, one can't access only some specific values of an array without having some kind of common condition relevant to those specific values. Am I correct?

Comment: And by the way, I have just noticed that the speed with which the new file gets created is actually faster if `your_csv` is smaller in size, and the speed is much slower if `your_csv` is huge. I mean, if you refresh the folder and see the file size changing, its much faster if the original csv is smaller, and vice versa. Like, it takes 10 times the time for a csv 3 times the size. Why is that so?

Comment: The way this is set up, yes, there's no easy way to index these in that manner. You could parse them as arrays, by using `your_csv = CSV.parse("your_csv.csv")`, then work with the resulting two dimensional array.

Comment: The reason it is so much slower with a larger file is partially because of the method I gave you to do this. I'll include a method that (I think) should be a little more efficient. If that doesn't help, it could be a memory thing.

Comment: Ok, so for example, I need to access only the first and the last elements of a column. How do I do that? I could not find any proper documentation of `parse`.

Comment: `parse` returns a regular two dimensional array. So any array methods will work. So you can access those by index (`your_csv[i][0]` and `your_csv[i][-1]` would correspond to each first and last column), or use `transpose` (`your_csv.transpose.first` and `your_csv.transpose.last`) to pull the entire column. Be aware `transpose` creates a new object that doesn't affect the original one. Reassigning the element by using the index will manipulate the object in place so you can write a new CSV directly with it though.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I have another question. Here, there was one column. Suppose there are many columns that I want to modify before copying them into a new CSV file. How to do that? I am asking because like `first`, there are no keywords like `second`, `third`. etc. So, I tried writing a code like this:

`CSV.open('original_file.csv') do |row|`
`CSV.foreach('new_file.csv', "wb") do |csv|`
`csv<<row`
`csv.shift`
`fifth_column = your_csv.map(&:first)`
`convert_platform = {"Android"=>1, "iOS"=>2}`
`converted_platform = fifth_column.map { |row|` `converted_platform[row]}`
`csv<<row`
`end`
`end`